# Parsley js check for errors before firing virtual pageview

Tags: javascript, forms, parsley.js

I've got a multistep form using Parsley js for the validation. I need to firstly validate the form and then fire a Google Analytics virtual pageview, currently it still fires the pageview if there's a validation error, this is the JavaScript that returns onsubmit of the form:

```
var gaPageView =
             function gaPageView() {
                 //alert("here");
                 if (div.form_elements_container.find('.parsley-error').length > 0) {
                     return;
                 }
                 else {
                     ga('send', 'pageview', 'virtual-pageview-here');
                 }
             };
```

So I'm checking it finds the attribute 'parsley-error' on the form field first before firing the pageview, but currently it still fires the pageview? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you bound `gaPageView`, but if you bind it on `parsley:form:validate` then you can simplify your code, not worry about validation errors or binding order, etc...

Comment: Many thanks, I wasn't aware I had to bind ga pageview, what would be the best way to bind it on parsley:form:validate?

Comment: Well, something has to call `gaPageView`, right? If you go up in the backtrace, at some point I imagine you'll get to function that is bound.

Comment: For binding to `parsley:form:validate`, check the doc :-)